# Is this the correct use of "framework"?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I am writing my master's thesis computer science and I want to open it with a sentence that reflects the whole work in a short way.

To that end, I have chosen to use the word "framework", but I am not sure if I have use it correctly.

> The framework of this thesis is the natural language processing and
>   machine learning methods applied to clinical text from electronic
>   patient records.

The sentence pretend to be an extension of a simpler and shorter sentence which I strongly believe that is correct:

> The framework of this work is clinical text mining.

My questions are:

- Is the longer sentence correct?
- Which sentence is most suitable as the opening of a thesis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that **framework** is quite the right word. The Oxford Dictionaries says [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/framework)

> **framework**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** An essential supporting structure of a building, vehicle, or object.
>   *a conservatory in a delicate framework of iron*
>
> **1.1** A basic structure underlying a system, concept, or text.
>   *the theoretical framework of political sociology*

But your usage concerns the *content* of the thesis.

I suggest that a better word would be **scope**, for which the Oxford Dictionaries has [this](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/scope)

> **scope**
>   NOUN
>
> **1** The extent of the area or subject matter that something deals with or to which it is relevant.
>   *such questions go beyond the scope of this book*

This would make your sentences

> The **scope** of this thesis is the natural language processing and machine learning methods applied to clinical text from electronic patient records.
>
> The **scope** of this work is clinical text mining.

Comment: _Scope_ doesn't feel quite right here either, to me. Perhaps _context_ might work? Or better yet, just rephrasing completely: “This thesis deals with methods of natural language processing and machine learning as applied to clinical texts from electronic patient records”.